# TextView is always shown as singleline on Android 2.x

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple TextView in a LinearLayout

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:maxLines="2"
     android:ellipsize="end" />
```

So I want a TextView with max. 2 lines. The TextViews text is set dynamically in a ListView Adapter. Everything looks fine on Android 4, but on Android 2 the text of the textview gets always ellipsized at the first line.

The problem is that `android:ellipsize="end"` is applied at the first line, even if there are two lines of text.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: try android:lines="2" and check

Comment: I have developed java method for these purpose

Answer (score 2):

do this

android:multiLine="true"

it will work for you.

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'multiLine' in package 
 'android'. Could also not find this xml attribute in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to achieve this

```
public void doEllipsize(final TextView tv, final int maxLine) {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if (maxLine <= 0) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3)
                            + "...";
                    tv.setText(text);
                } else if (tv.getLineCount() >= maxLine) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3)
                            + "...";
                    tv.setText(text);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**How to use**

put this method in your activity and call after findViewById()

```
TextView yourTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtv);
        doEllipsize(yourTv,2);
```